# spark list control showing incomplete data on dataProvider update

Tags: list, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark

when i am updating a spark list like this:

```
searchView.gridView.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection( data );
```

i sometimes get the full data from the array "data" displayed in the list, but sometimes only the first four items. i checked and both the array and the dataProvider after setting it always have the correct number of entries.

here is the list code from the mxml:

```
<s:List id="gridView" width="1024" height="390" itemRenderer="com.xxx.xxx.view.component.GridViewItemRenderer">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout rowHeight="195" columnWidth="242" requestedColumnCount="4" horizontalGap="0" verticalGap="0" />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

i can't figure out why it sometimes shows everything and then again shows just the first row.

UPDATE: it seems to be somehow connected to using the TileLayout. when i remove the layout it always displays all entries.

UPDATE 2: it also seems to only occur when i go from no items in the dataprovider (empty array) to n items. if there are already items displayed and the dataprovider gets updated with more or less items it works.

Comment: How do you populate your array ? Through a remote service ?

Comment: the array is returned from a service singleton through a function call. the array is built within the function call but has no connection to a remote service. this is what sets the "data" array prior to setting the data provider. also, the count of the array is correct at all times.

Comment: try invalidatedisplaylist() after the assignation of dataprovider

Comment: did that, but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I just used a band aid though. If you do this, it should show all.

```
var myLayout:LayoutBase = gridView.layout;
gridView.layout = null;
gridView.layout = myLayout;
```

Another option is just to create a new layout object and set it after the dataProvider.

```
var newLayout = new TileLayout();
newLayout.rowHeight = 195;
newLayout.columnWidth = 242;
newLayout.requestedColumnCount = 4;
newLayout.horizontalGap = 0;
newLayout.verticalGap = 0;

gridView.dataProvider = newDataProvider;
gridView.layout = newLayout;
```